# sqlite3 version not updating via Anaconda (Windows)

Tags: python, sqlite, anaconda, conda

I have a freshly installed version of Anaconda (Windows 10). I need to update my sqlite3. Whenever I do `conda install -c anaconda sqlite` it downloads the package and updates. But when I check then the latest version it is still the old one??

Comment: We're going to need more information than this. Where did you update the package, where did you check the version, etc. ?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. sorry could solve, it found somewhere completely different an sql file which I replaced with the latest one, then it worked